# how to automatically run "specified shortkey in vimrc" after vim is started

Tags: vim

I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <silent>tt :NERDTreeToggle<CR>:se nu<CR>
```

Is there a way to call/run/press `tt` automatically right after **vim** is started by `vim` command in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vim -c 'norm tt'` should do it (see `:h :normal`). To do it automatically for every vim invocation ... hmm.

You could add an alias to your .bashrc or equivalent: `alias vim='vim -c "norm tt"'`

You could also just put `norm tt` at the end of your .vimrc. Or indeed simply

```
NERDTreeToggle
set nu
```

Comment: thank you very much. vim -c 'norm tt' does work. But when I put "norm tt" in the end of my .vimrc - getting error: Error detected while processing /Users/whitesiroi/.vimrc:
line  209:
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTreeToggle
Press ENTER or type command to continue